# SharePoint 2013 - customize look and feel of some site pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Through SharePoint 2013, there are some site pages that I would like to brand, while others can continue to use oslo default look and feel.  What is the best way to add a style sheet to a selected site page?  or change the default look and feel of a selected site page?

I do not want to edit the default admin master template...I simply want my site page to have it's own look and feel.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding the style sheet via script editor webpart?

Comment: no i haven't, but I need the entire page styled...not just a specific area inside of the body element

Comment: Having a content editor to load the css on load.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link the external style sheet, which would be for the entire page. Add the Script Editor web part to the page and within the snippet add:

```
<link type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css" />
```

To add the stylesheet to the head section, add the Script Editor web part and insert the following snippet:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.href = '/_catalogs/Styles/mystylesheet.css';
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: but mystylesheet.css is being injected into the page...its not loading into the head of the page.

Comment: this will not work, I only want to skin some of the site pages, not apply a snippet for all of them from the master page.

Comment: Well, you'd only add snippet to the Script Editor web part for the SitePages you'd want to be branded.

Comment: how do we edit an individual site page so that we can apply a snippet to it? what are the steps

Comment: What are you referring to when you say Site Pages? did you mean Site Pages library that holds wiki page and web part pages or something else?

Comment: Yes site pages library that we access from the browser inside of site contents.

Comment: All the pages in that library are individual pages. Browse to the page. To edit the page, from the ribbon click edit page

Comment: haha - I know I can do that.  I want to do more than that, I want to change the look and feel the entire page :)

Comment: Thank you for battling through this with me.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found this documentation on Microsoft's site to be more useful.

> Place the custom CSS files in the Themable folder in the Style library
>   (not the Themable folder in the Master Page Gallery). Only CSS files
>   that are stored in the Themable folder in the Style library are
>   recognized by the theming engine. The Themable folder is created
>   automatically for publishing sites. Otherwise, you can create the
>   Themable folder in the correct location (http://
>   SiteCollectionName/Style Library/language/Themable/).
>
> You can name it custom.css and just reference it on the master page.
>   Replace CSSFileLocation with the location of the CSS file. The
>   following is an example of an `<SharePoint:CssRegistration>` element.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn266906.aspx

Comment: can you provide a particular passage from the link that you are referring you? msdn links are notorious for changing.

Comment: Place the custom CSS files in the Themable folder in the Style library (not the Themable folder in the Master Page Gallery). Only CSS files that are stored in the Themable folder in the Style library are recognized by the theming engine. The Themable folder is created automatically for publishing sites. Otherwise, you can create the Themable folder in the correct location (http:// SiteCollectionName/Style Library/language/Themable/).

Comment: You can name it custom.css and just reference it on the master page.

Replace CSSFileLocation with the location of the CSS file.

The following is an example of an <SharePoint:CssRegistration> element.

Comment: @EricAlexander I hope that it answered your question.